# Can I export a ipython notebook to pdf without any in the In/Out lines?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I'd like to create a document with the ipython notebook, and display the results of computations in a nice formatted table.  Is there anyway I could export the results of my computations in my notebook to a pdf without seeing any of the In[]/Out[] lines?